# Zabbix - item key does not work, "Remote commands are not enabled"

Tags: powershell, zabbix

I want to run a powershell script with `zabbix_agentd`. I use for this a test item `system.run[dir,nowait]`, but it doesn't work. I get this message:

[image: Error message screenshot]

I want to know why that does not work.

Answer (score 1):

We have not so much information about your problem, anyway if you already have enabled the `EnableRemoteCommands` maybe you are just involved in this limitation:

> *Remote commands do not work with active Zabbix agents.*
>
> ― [Zabbix documentation](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/4.0/manual/config/notifications/action/operation/remote_command) 4.0 and 5.0

If you are using an active agent, try with a passive configuration (or implement a Zabbix Proxy, or put them on a VPN, or connect them through an SSH tunnel, etc. You have some options out of the scope of this question to overcome this limitation).

Answer (score 0):

First, and not directly related to the question - if you specify the `nowait` parameter, the item won't get any data.

Second, the error message in this case is rather self-explanatory - "Remote commands are not enabled". Your best bet would be to look up the `EnableRemoteCommands` parameter in the [Zabbix documentation](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/4.2/manual/appendix/config/zabbix_agentd).

Comment: i put EnableRemoteCommands=1 and LogRemoteCommands=1 and restart zabbix agent but not work, always same message "remote commands are not enabled", i don't know why  @Richlv

Comment: That turns into a troubleshooting session, which is not that appropriate here. To make it more useful, please post detailed information on what you tried and how it failed. Preferably testing with `zabbix_get`, showing how you determined that the agent was successfully restarted etc.

Comment: i have this message in zabbix server log "became not supported: Remote commands are not enabled.", i troubleshoot by create always new item and this command "cat zabbix_server.log | grep "CPU_percent" @Richlv

Comment: when i use zabbix get i have this message :  zabbix_get -s ip  -k C:\zabbix\conf\ProcessPid.exe
ZBX_NOTSUPPORTED: Invalid item key format. @Richlv

Comment: Please make sure to consult the documentation at least a bit - this is too much handholding for this site. While you could ask for a troubleshooting help in the Zabbix IRC channel, even there at least some effort to check the available documentation would be needed.

Answer (score 0):

To use powershell script, use UserParameter in this way.

copy script in zabbix folder

UserParameter=YOURKEY,powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy unrestricted -File SCriptLocation\Script.ps1

restart agent

use zabbix_get -s server -k YOURKEY

If your script is taking more time, chant the Timeout value.